# php: Form to reveal more options depending on which radio button checked

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a form for entering Computer or Televisions as electronics. I want first the user to select which of the two he's entering, and depending on which one he chooses, he's going to have different stuff to fill in.

I tried to write this but it doesn't work. I get an error on $answer= $_POST['type'];
Please let me know what is wrong, I'm kind of new at php. Thanks.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <h3 style="color:blue;">Type of Item</h1>

        <form name ="form1" method ="post"> 
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Computer"> Computer<br>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Television"> Television<br>
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php 
        $answer = $_POST['type'];  
        if ($answer == "Computer") {          
            //show stuff    
        }
        else {
            //show other stuff
        }          
    ?>
```

Comment: Your form needs a submit button or JavaScript to handle the click event

Comment: PHP would require a page submit before $_POST would have anything in it - javascript/jquery can do this without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` will be empty until the form is actually submitted. Your form does not have a submit button. That said, this type of task is usually better done in javascript since it doesn't require a full page reload just to open up the next set of options in a form.

Here's an example of how this might work using a simple javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleOptions() {
    if ( document.getElementById('type_Computer').checked ) {
        document.getElementById('nextSetOfComputerOptions').style.display = '';
        } else {
        document.getElementById('nextSetOfComputerOptions').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>


<input type="radio" name="type" id="type_Computer" value="Computer" onclick="toggleOptions();">

<div id="nextSetOfComputerOptions" style="display:none;">
<!-- more form fields -->
</div>
```